# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed. Asyncio

Tags: python, asyncio

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from time import time
import aiofiles


async def fetch_content(url, session):
    async with session.get(url, allow_redirects=True) as response:
        data = await response.read()
        await write(data)


async def write(data):
    filename = f"file-{int(time() * 1000)}.jpeg"
    async with aiofiles.open(filename, mode='wb') as file:
        await file.write(data)


async def main():
    url = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240'
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(10):
            task = asyncio.create_task(fetch_content(url, session))
            tasks.append(task)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Не понимаю в чем ошибка, код выполняется, картинки сохраняются, но код выдает ошибку

Comment: В коде все коректно, в идеальных условиях выполняется на ура))

Comment: А какую ошибку?